# how to put a model in a different file in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a new express.js application and I want to put my model in a different file using sequelize.

In my root dir I have a db.js that have this code

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

// connect to MySql database
const db = new Sequelize('mysql://root:password@localhost:8889/myDB');

module.exports = db;

I'm exporting the db
```

Now in my root directory I have a models folder and inside the model folder I have a user.js file and in there I have this code.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../db')

const user = db.def('user', {
    firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
})

module.exports = user;
```

this give me this error.

```
db.def is not a function
```

I have merge the two files together it works, but it doesn't work i I break it in two separate files it doesn't.

It there's something I don't understand about export modules?

Comment: What is `db.def`? To define a model you need to use `sequelize.define` function.

Comment: I figure the const db inherits the new instance of Sequelize therefor i can use it do define the model. I'm requiring the db that has the new instance of New Sequelize.

Comment: thanks for you help. I missed understood you answer. I can post it as the approve answer.

Comment: Have you tried using [sequelize-cli][1]? It can help you create models (and migrations) in one of the ways on how you can structure your node.js code.


  [1]: https://github.com/sequelize/cli